# Origen, o existencia siquiera, del verbo "amocar"

Tags: etimología, vocabulario-técnico, españa

En la zona de Cartagena (y por extensión, Murcia), se dice que alguien "**amoca**" o "**se la amoca**" cuando es el que le toca la china para empezar a jugar (o sea: el que le toca contar y buscar, jugando al escondite; pillar, jugando a la pilla; etc.).
El verbo, a la vista del uso, es algo así como "**amocar**". Ejemplos:

> *¿Quién se la amoca? Se la amocaba Pedro. ¡Pedro, amocas tú! ¡Yo no amoco, le toca a Juan que yo me la he "amocao" tres veces ya!*

Sin embargo, ['amocar', según el DLE, no existe](http://dle.rae.es/?w=amocar).

El caso es que buscando por ["se la amoca" en Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22se%20la%20amoca%22) salen unos cuantos casos de gente mencionando la expresión.
Luego es cierto que, a nivel fonético, se usa o usaba un verbo que suena como "amocar".

Las preguntas son: ¿existe o existió alguna vez este verbo? En caso afirmativo, ¿cuál es su origen y etimología? Y en caso negativo, ¿existe algún otro verbo con ese significado, que suene parecido y que quizá se estuviera pronunciando mal?

Comment: Interesante cuestión. En Málaga capital se usaba en mis tiempos, años 80, la frase "se la moga" para indicar lo mismo. Tiene un sonido parecido y como ocurre con la tuya, los verbos mogar o amogar no se recogen en el DRAE tampoco

Comment: Esta palabra me recuerda **camuca**. Tambien por los año 80, soliamos jugar un juego de naipes parecido al Rummy. La regla era que el jugador en turno no podía colocar en el pozo una carta con el mismo número que la carta superior del mismo porque **camuca**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- "Amocar" parece ser una palabra [gallega](https://es.glosbe.com/gl/es/amocar) con el significado de "fastidiar"
- "Amocar" aparece en el [**Diccionario General de la Lengua Asturiana**](https://mas.lne.es/diccionario/palabra/36351) con las acepciones de "Perjudicar, fastidiar" y "“Birlarle a uno las pesetas tontamente”
- En el [**DLE**](http://www.rae.es/) no figura "amocar".
- En el [**NTLLE**](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) solo aparece "amocar" en el Diccionario de Rodríguez y Navas (1918): *Galicia*. Enfadar, disgustar, apenar.
- En el [**CORDE**](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) no aparece "amocar".
- En el [**CREA**](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html) no aparece "amocar".
- En el [**Fichero general de la RAE**](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) aparecen  8 fichas al buscar "amocar": una referente a un tipo de gusano, cinco hacen referencia a "sonarse los mocos" y dos citan a Emilia García Cotorruelo (*Estudios sobre el habla de Cartagena y su comarca*, 1959); el significado que se da a [**amocar**](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_A/LETRA_A_PDF/AMOCAR/00000537.pdf) en éstas es "Doblar el cuerpo apoyando las manos en las rodillas para aguantar el peso de los que saltan" (Cartagena y extramuros).

En otras páginas de internet dedicadas a expresiones de Cartagena también figura:

- [Michirones Cartageneros](https://ar-ar.facebook.com/MICHIRONES.CARTAGENEROS/posts/expresiones-cartagenerasa-a-coscoletas-expresi%C3%B3n-de-subir-a-un-ni%C3%B1o-a-la-espalda/10151398358284913/): "Amocar: En un juego infantil, por ejemplo el escondite, aquel que le toca contar y buscar."
- [Cartagena de levante](https://cartagenadelevante.com/2015/03/18/chapullete-2/#more-2159): "AMOCAR: Tocar la peor parte de inicio o sorteo en los juegos infantiles."
- [Expresiones típicas cartageneras](https://bastedm.es.tl/Expresiones-tipicas-cartageneras.htm): "AMOCAR: En un juego infantil como el escondite, aquel que le toca contar y buscar."

En conclusión:

- **Amocar** sí existe en otras lenguas (gallego, asturiano) pero con significados totalmente diferentes al buscado por el OP.
- Se ha utilizado como variante de [**mocar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PSKd5Qg) ("Sonar y limpiar los mocos.") en otra zonas.
- Tiene / tenía un uso muy circunscrito a Cartagena con la acepción que el OP señala ("Tocar la peor parte de inicio o sorteo en los juegos infantiles.", "En un juego infantil, aquel que le toca contar y buscar.") y quizás su origen proceda de la definición recogida en las fichas del Fichero General de la RAE referentes a los [***Estudios sobre el habla de Cartagena***](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_A/LETRA_A_PDF/AMOCAR/00000537.pdf).